# Pgfplots Filled Contour and Memory Problems

Tags: pgfplots

I would appreciate some TeX wisdom on the following.

I have some two dimensional data I'd like to generate some filled contour plots with in `pgfplots`. I have a mesh grid of x and y coordinates and then the plotted data as well (the "z" coordinate). The grid is roughly 500 by 200 nodes. I wrote data to a text file as described in the manual. I only did it to three significant figures to save space. The resulting text file is < 5 MB.

When I try to compile my contour plot I get a "TeX memory exceeded" error. I've tried doing it in a `standalone` document and using the externalization feature from the manual but I still get the memory error.

Is this silly of me to even try given the amount of data? Perhaps I should downsample it before printing to file? Or manually increase the TeX memory on my computer?

If possible I'd prefer to stick with `pgfplots`. I've created the figure in MATLAB and used `export_fig` to create a PDF of the plot for inclusion in the main document. It looks okay but still not quite what I was hoping for.

Comment: The `pgfplots` manual has a full subsection on this. It is subsection 6.1 in v1.16. One thing that may help is to use `lualatex` to compile the document.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a read. I've never used lualatex before.